# How to convert dict to DF

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to convert this json to the below expected output, but I'm not getting what I want. Please help!

```
a = {
    "k1": [
        [
            "xyz1",
            "type1"
        ],
        [
            "xyz2",
            "type2"
        ]
    ],
    "k2": [
        [
            1,
            "a"
        ],
        [
            2,
            "b"
        ]
    ]
}
```

The expected output is:

```
k1,xyz1,type1 
k1,xyz2,type2 
k2,1,a
k2,2,b
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Your expected output is not a list. What type are you looking for?

Comment: import json

aList = json.dumps(jsonString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With list comprehension:

```
pd.DataFrame([[k] + v for k, vs in a.items() for v in vs])
```

Output:

```
    0     1      2
0  k1  xyz1  type1
1  k1  xyz2  type2
2  k2     1      a
3  k2     2      b
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input format will never change, and that the output you're after is precisely:

```
[['k1', 'xyz1', 'type1'],
 ['k1', 'xyz2', 'type2'],
 ['k2', 1, 'a'],
 ['k2', 2, 'b']]
```

Then a solution with no dependencies is:

```
# list to hold our output
out_rows = []
# iterate over outer keys, which will form the first column
for i,j in a.items():
    # iterate over inner array which will form each row of the output
    for row in j:
        # build our new row
        out_row = [i]
        # add the detail from the inner array row
        out_row.extend(row)
        # add this to our output
        out_rows.append(out_row)
```

You can then put this in a dataframe if you'd like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(out_rows)
```